# Skip jsx's div wrapping in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array object that used this component to display a UI. I have a problem, my style broke because of an extra .

```
<ul className="dropdown-menu">
    {map(listItems, (obj,i) => 
        <li key={i} onClick={e => dropdownHandler(obj.handlerName)}>
          {obj.visible && <div>
                  <a>
                    {obj.iconClasses && 
                        <i className={obj.iconClasses}></i>
                    }
                    {obj.name}
                  </a>
                  <div key={i} className={classnames({'divider':obj.divider})}></div>
              </div>
          }
        </li>
    )}
</ul>
```

In the line of `{obj.visible ..` what else can I do? I do not want to include a `div`.

Comment: so basically you want to display the <a> and the <div> without wrapping them in a <div>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use two conditionals and omit the wrapping element:

```
<li key={i} onClick={e => dropdownHandler(obj.handlerName)}>
  {obj.visible &&
    <a>
      {obj.iconClasses && 
        <i className={obj.iconClasses}></i>
      }
      {obj.name}
    </a>
  }
  {obj.visible &&
    <div key={i} className={classnames({'divider':obj.divider})}></div>
  }
</li>
```

Furthermore using array indexes as keys is an anti-pattern. You should use some business keys instead. More info in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/2030321).

Answer (score 0):

To put the condition inside `JSX`, we can use the `ternary operator`, like this:

```
{1==1 ? <div> hello </div> : null}
```

Return `null` if you don't want to render anything when condition fails.

Use this:

```
<li key={i} onClick={e => dropdownHandler(obj.handlerName)}>
      {obj.visible ? 
           <a>
              {obj.iconClasses && 
                   <i className={obj.iconClasses}></i>
              }
              {obj.name}
           </a>
       : null}
       {obj.visible ? 
           <div key={i} className={classnames({'divider':obj.divider})}></div>
       : null}
</li>
```

Comment: the div is there too, what's the different?

Comment: sorry, forgot to break that part, check the updated answer.

Comment: You can use React.Children.only(), checkout the documentation

Answer (score 0):

One of the shortcomings of React is that you need to wrap every block in a single container. They are [working on the solution](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127), but it might take a while. In the meantime, the simplest way to skip the extra `<div` in your case is to do the check for both elements under it separately:

```jsx
{obj.visible &&
  <a>
    {obj.iconClasses && 
      <i className={obj.iconClasses}></i>
    }
    {obj.name}
  </a>
{obj.visible && <div key={i} className={classnames({'divider':obj.divider})}></div>}
```